# Joining two tables and excluding rows already seen before

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I am trying to join two tables. Table x and y. 
Table x

```
Product_x   ID       Date   Quantity
   A            1         7/1/2019    1100
   B            1         7/1/2019    200
```

Table y

```
Product_y   ID       Date   Used_Quantity
  A         1        7/1/2019      665
  B         1        7/1/2019      29
```

I am joining on Company ID, Date and Product B. This the output, I would get:

```
Product_x   Product_y   ID  Date        Quantity    Used_Quantity
A              A            1   5/1/2019    1100    NULL
B              A            1   5/1/2019    200 665
B              B            1   5/1/2019    200 29
```

However, I want to exclude the middle row. I don't want the middle row because Product A from Table y has already occurred in Table x and therefore I don't want it's corresponding data from Table y. My desired would be:

```
Product_x   Product_y   ID  Date        Quantity    Used_Quantity
A               B            1  5/1/2019    1100    NULL
B               B            1  5/1/2019    200 29
```

Is there a way I can modify my existing query below.

```
Select * from x
left join y on
(x.ID = y.ID and x.Date=y.Date and x.Product_x = B)
```

Comment: Do you need `x left join y` or a regular inner join will do? If it will, this can be solved with `y cross apply (top 1 from x)`

Comment: @Timekiller an outer apply would be the equivalent of a left join.

Comment: @MarcGuillot yes, but you'll have to swap the tables to complete OP's requirements (start with y, join 1 row from x). If he wants `x left join y` after all then this doesn't hold since it doesn't account for `x` without matching `y`. That could be addressed with a union but it's pretty ugly IMO.

Comment: Thanks guys. I do need a left join. Any thoughts how this can be easily accomplished?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to want a simple `inner join`:

```
select *
from x join
     y
     on x.ID = y.ID and
        x.Date = y.Date and
        x.Product_x = y.product_y;
```

Comment: The inner join won't work. I want a left join. I want to keep the first row as well and show the Used_Quantity as NULL. I want the join on ID, Date and Product B...any ideas? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line to the end of your query:

```
WHERE Product_x = ISNULL(Product_y, Product_x)
```

Or, if you prefer the logic spelled out a bit more:

```
WHERE Product_x = Product_y 
    OR Product_y IS NULL
```